# .htaccess and mod_rewrite | always use www. exception for virtual subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

i am using .htaccess and mod_rewrite to force always "www." in URL - for other stuff too of course. This is the part of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/images\/ [NC] [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.com/ [NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^images/([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+).jpg$ pic.php?picID=$1&width=$2&height=$3&corners=$4
```

Now i'm looking forward to use virtual subdomains to speed up image-loading (like: img1., img2., etc.). The reason is i've a lot of thumbnails on some of my pages.

But allways when I try to load an image via virtual subdomain - for example:

```
http://img1.example.com/images/672_1000_0_0.jpg
```

I get something like that:

```
http://www.example.com/pic.php?picID=672&width=1000&height=0&corners=0
```

I would be very grateful for a solution to my problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem lately, the trick is to use additional RewriteCond clauses (on the 2. line):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^img1.example.com$ [NC] [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^img2.example.com$ [NC] [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^img3.example.com$ [NC] [OR]
```

If you have unlimited virtual subdomains it's probably best to replace that with a regex directly, like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^img([0-9]+).example.com$ [NC] [OR]
```

Hope to have helped!

Comment: Well, that worked fine so far. But now I have a new problem: I can enter my whole page through the subdomains. This means a lot of duplicated Content. So i want it only to work inside this path: http://img1.example.com/images/ etc.

Comment: I haven't tried this out but i guess it would work if you add another RewriteCond at the end of your first block that matches the request part of the URL like this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^images/ [NC]`
Another solution would be to create 301 redirects for all duplicate content pages, i think that might be a bit tedious though, depending on the size of your application.

Comment: I just looked at your code again and it seems you already do this on the first line of your RewriteCond statement - it should actually be working like this, only you don't need to escape the slashes, as they don't need to be escaped in Regular Expressions.